# Can't connect to FTP server

Tags: networking, ssh, ftp, file-transfer

I tried connecting FTP server using both active and passive mode even behind router and direct connection, none worked.

I tried disabling firewall, anti-virus still nothing is helping.

```
Status: Resolving address of kandlalogistics.com
Status: Connecting to 198.15.81.91:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 19:56. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: What client are you using? I just tested with my Phone and passed SSL/TLS phase just fine. Your client supports TLS, right?

Comment: Yes it supports , I am using FileZilla. Actually it is working on serveral other machines and not working on my particular one.May be it is issue with my pc. Firewalls and Avs are off

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but is the time on your local machine correct? So the server cert looks valid...

Comment: It is not stupid question at all.See It is working fine with other stuffs and One wierd thing i noticed is my laptop wasn't able to connect at home with dsl modem and same laptop was able to connect at office. 
So does ISP affect ?

Comment: Were you able to know if ISP affects?

Comment: Certainly it is, I called a person from ISP we traced IP route we came to know that for some subnet masks it is not working, they changed my ip for a while and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article explaining [why FTPS may get blocked while unsecured FTP works](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2175978).

Essentially the author means firewalls may inspect the FTP protocol to find which data port to open, and fail if they don't support TLS.

So, yes, it may be your ISP is blocking your access. Not sure about a reasonable workaround though.